# Power Query IF Parameter Advanced Editor

Tags: excel, powerquery, sql-server-2017

I have the following dilemma...

The data is stored in SQL as `BIT` i.e. 1 or 0.

My Parameter in my sheet is defined by the user i.e. Yes or No.

When the parameter checks, it obviously picks it up with the following code:

```
let
//Pull in a values from the parameter table
SQL = fnGetParameter("SQL"),
dbName = fnGetParameter("DB"),
ValuationDate = Text.From(fnGetParameter("Valuation Date")),
ActiveItem = Text.From(fnGetParameter("Active Items")),

if ActiveItem = "No" then "1" else "0"

    Source = Sql.Database(SQL, dbName,

    [Query="
```

The problem I'm facing is, how do I write/develop in the Advanced Editor to switch the Yes / No to 1 / 0?

I tried it with the following code (which can also be seen above):

```
if ActiveItem = "No" then "1" else "0"
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of struggle, I managed to get it right.

I changed my get parameter from :

```
ActiveItem = Text.From(fnGetParameter("Active Items")),
```

To:

```
ActiveItem = Text.From(if fnGetParameter("Active Items") = "Yes" then 1 else 0),
```

This worked like a charm.

My final Code looks like this:

```
let
//Pull in a values from the parameter table
SQL = fnGetParameter("SQL"),
dbName = fnGetParameter("DB"),
ValuationDate = Text.From(fnGetParameter("Valuation Date")),
ActiveItem = Text.From(if fnGetParameter("Active Items") = "Yes" then 1 else 0),


    Source = Sql.Database(SQL, dbName,

    [Query="
```